# Maven plugin development - how to get list of goals

Tags: java, maven, mojo

I'm developing a Maven plugin. From inside that plugin I want to get the list of goals for the current execution and make decisions based on whether a particular goal was called (install or deploy, for example). 
How do I do that?

Comment: `mvn pluginname:help` will give you the list of available goals within a plugin.

Comment: For what purpose do you need the list of goals within the plugin itself ?

Comment: maven has predefined life cycles with order. see [https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html]
So when you at certain goal ( ex: install ) you know goals upto that certain goal, are already executed. For example in "install" phase all the previous phases upto "install" are executed. i.e validate , compile ,compile , test, package , integration-test, verify

Comment: Yes, I know that. I want to know is there a way to find which predefined life cycle goals were called, from inside my Mojo's execute method. I need my plugin to have one behaviour when it is executed in the "install" phase and another when it is executed in the "deploy" phase. The way I see things is I need to get the list of goals for the current execution (from inside my mojo) and check if it has "deploy". Does this make any sense?

P.S. I'm coming with a Gradle background and I'm quite new to Maven. Is it okay that I think of Maven goals the same way I think of Gradle tasks?

Comment: You should write two Mojo's, one that by default is associated with the `install` phase and another that's associated with the `deploy` phase.  If they share behavior put the shared behavior in a base class